# Eliminating declared, but unused polymorphic classes during link time

Tags: g++, elf

I've got a library which defines a base class and a set of derived classes. There's a single header that declares them all. Now, library users may not need all derived classes. I had expected that linking with `g++ -Wl,--gc-sections` would eliminate those unused classes, including vtables and virtual functions. Yet I still see those classes in the final result (checked with `nm`).

I supect that's because all `vtable` are weak symbols, defined almost everywhere. And as `--gc-sections` fails to eliminate these vtables, they drag in the associated virtual functions, and from there on it's all downhill. Is this true?

I'm not using .so's, so `-fvisibility` should not be needed, right?

I'm used to Visual Studio, which seems to be far more efficient in removing unused functions.

Answer (score 1):

> I had expected that linking with g++ -Wl,--gc-sections would eliminate those unused classes

The `--gc-sections` can only eliminate unused *sections*.

You likely want to compile with `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections`. That way, every function will be in its own section, which the `--gc-sections` will then be able to eliminate (if unused).